# Can't get a child div to match the variable height of either its parent or partner column

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'll try and format the post so it's accessible:

- **The problem:**

I'm having a bit of a frustrating time trying to get one column div (a sidebar) to match the height of either its parent, or the column to its left. I've tried doing it by pure CSS and then by jQuery and thus far haven't been able to find a resolve. 
The content inside the page is content-managed (Wordpress + Boostrap), and the base itself is used as a template for three other pages, so a fixed-height solution wouldn't really be useful here.

Also there are the remnants of the last jQuery attempt I tried, from a solution on StackOverflow for another - quite similar- problem. This didnt work out, but I've left the code in (colh-parent on the parent div, colh-child on the two child columns and jQuery in the header) in case it helps anyone understand what I'm trying to achieve.

I've also tried a method involving floating the parent container and the children whcih didn't seem to have any effect either. I'm not too experienced at the moment, and this problem seems to be a little over my head.

- **The page in question:**

http://okamistudio.com/ssawp/pennants/

- **The goal:**

I'm trying to make the blue side strip meet the bottom of the white page, like in this page (though in that page it's being forced down by the content):

http://okamistudio.com/ssawp/about-us/

What I'm trying to achieve is for the blue background of the sidebar (div.subpage-sidebar) to meet the bottom of the white strip. As I understand it this would require its parent (div.span3) to meet the height of either its partner column (div.span6) or the parent (div.row / .colh-parent).

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the problem; the page looks okay to me.  Maybe you could take a screenshot and highlight what is wrong

Comment: If you check here: http://okamistudio.com/ssawp/about-us/

You see that, albeit forced by padding, the sidebar connects with the bottom, splitting the white block visually/graphically. This is what I'm trying to achieve on the page listed in the OP. I hope that makes it a little clearer, and apologies - I'm not too good at communicating my code-related issues.

Comment: Are you suggesting that this can be done with jQuery or should JavaScript not be a requirement?

Comment: jQuery or CSS (or a mixture of the two), it doesn't matter as long as it's an efficient solution. I have to pop out for around 20m, I just don't want you to think I'm snubbing you by suddenly not replying. I appreciate your interest and am keen to find out what's been preventing it from working from my own attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this using absolute positioning for the sidebar.  Maybe not the most desirable depending, but I have tested it and it seems to look exactly like you want.

```
.colh-parent {
    position: relative;
}
.span3 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Ah brilliant, just implemented it and it works a trick - thank you! May I enquire as to why it might not be the most desirable option, for my own knowledge. You're right though, this is exactly what I was after and it doesn't appear to have caused any issues elsewhere. Thanks once again, really appreciated.

Comment: @OkamiStudio don't forget to upvote/accept answers.  If it works it's desirable, but absolute positioning can cause problems sometimes .. even relative positioning can depending on the circumstances.  It's not something to avoid, but I just don't want to mess up your entire site's layout.

Comment: Thank you for that, I did try but was at 13 reputation at the time. I now can (woo!) and you're officially my first upvote. Thank you for the additional info and concern, you've saved me a prelonged headache. Have a cracking night!